# Block email delegation deletion in Google Apps for Business

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I'm thinking of using Google Apps for Business for my website. I'm the president of a fanclub and I need the secretary to access the fanclub email account, to send and forward emails from that account, but no deletion ability to delete emails.

I've read about email delegation but I didn't see anything mentioned about blocking email deletion.

Is this possible with Google Apps for Business?

Answer (score 1):

You can add on Google Vault to keep a copy of all emails even if deleted.
Or a backup service like Backupify.
http://www.refractiv.co.uk/google-apps-for-business/google-apps-add-ons/

You could also use Groups for shared email addresses, and limit who is allowed to delete "posts" (aka emails).